# how to insert data in database using dropdown with foreach loop

Tags: php, html

here i am creating a attendance sheet that insert data into the database 
after clicking submit button. The insertion of the data is base on the 2 
radio button which is absent/present, the problem is after clicking submit 
button the other component works accordingly except for the dropdown button, 
the dropdown button insert only a single string instead of the service time 
by the way i declare the service time in the database as varchar so i am 
confident that it's not the database that causes the error. maybe someone 
can help me any help is much appreciated. thank you in advance
    enter code here

```
<?php
include("Sampledb.php");
include("Sample.php");
$flag=0;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id1=>$attendance_status)
        {
        $name=$_POST['name'][$id1];
        $id=$_POST['id'][$id1];
        $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
        $servicetime=$_POST['servicetime'][$id1];


        $result=mysqli_query($objconn,"insert into 
        attendrecord(id,name,attendance_status,attendance_date,servicetime)

        values('$id','$name','$attendance_status','$date','$servicetime')");            
            if($result)
            {
                $flag=1;
            }                   

        }
    header("Location:sampleindex.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel panel-heading">

<form action="sampleindex.php" method="Post"> 

<label>Service time:</label>
<select name="servicetime">
<option>00:00</option>
<option value="7:30-9:30">7:30-9:30</option>
<option value="10:30-12:30">10:30-12:30</option>
<option value="1:30-3:30">1:30-3:30</option>
<option value="4:30-6:30">4:30-6:30</option>
</select>

<a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="view.php">View all<a/>


</div>
</div> 

<div id="alert" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-success" ">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
<strong>Success!</strong>Save
</div>

<h3>
<div class="well text-center">Date:<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?> </div>
</h3>

<div class="panel panel-body">


<tr>
<table class="table table-striped">
</tr>

<th>ID Number</th><th>Member Name</th><th>Attendace Status</th> 
<?php $result=mysqli_query($objconn,"select* from attend");
$id = 0;
$counter=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id++;
?>


<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"name="id[]">
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"name="name[]">
<td> 
<input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" 
value="present">Present
<input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" 
value="absent">Absent
</td>
</tr>   
<?php
$counter++;
}

?>
</table>    

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return mess();">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mess()
{
    if($flag=1){
    alert ("Record Save!");
    return true;}
    else
    alert ("Record Not Save!");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#alert').css('display','block');
    });
});
</script>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: sorry about the indention sir, it's my first time to post question here but in my actual code is properly indented but still thanks for the advice ill take note about it..

Answer (score 1):

Your service time is not an array as it keeps same for all record. So you need to change your PHP code as below:

```
$servicetime=$_POST['servicetime'];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks a lot  sir that's really work .. your a life saver hahahhahhaa

Comment: Great, happy that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_POST['servicetime'][$id]` use `$_POST['servicetime']`